# Cleaning numeric data in Pandas with apply + lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, series

I am cleaning some product and found one issue is below line-

```
    feed_df['sale_price'] = feed_df['sale_price'].apply(lambda x: x if x > 0 else None)
```

Here I have checked the data type of sale price is object.

Error is:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

So how can I change my lambda expression to fix this issue?

Comment: When you read the error message, what do you think does it mean?

Comment: sale price is string and I am comparing it with integer. So what should be a right way- change in lambda expression or putting a check before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you term "cleaning" is actually making your data dirty. Pandas specializes in vectorised operations. Otherwise, using Pandas would be little better than using lists and dictionaries of values.

What this means is you should ensure numeric series have numeric dtype. The alternative `object` dtype can hold arbitrary types, but is little more than a series of pointers, much like `list`. On the other hand, a numeric series will be held in memory as a contiguous memory block. You will see improvements in performance and memory usage.

In this case, you can use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` and then update your series conditionally. Values which cannot be converted to numeric will come through as `NaN`.

```
feed_df['sale_price'] = pd.to_numeric(feed_df['sale_price'], errors='coerce')
feed_df.loc[feed_df['sale_price'] <= 0, 'sale_price'] = np.nan
```

Notice we use `np.nan` instead of `None`. This is intentional. `NaN` ("Not a Number") is considered a `float`, while `None` is one of those arbitrary types which *forces* Pandas to use `object` dtype. We don't want that. Stick to a numeric dtype for numeric data and you'll be happy.

Comment: Thanks @jpp for the explanation.